# Save content rich text editor to blob field in mysql database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, richtext

I'm trying to save the content from a rich text editor (ckeditor in my case) to my a blob field in my database.

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class ArticleViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Article Body")]
    public string ArticleBody { get; set; }

}
```

The Article Body is my rich text field like this in my view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleBody)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ArticleBody, new { placeholder = "Type the content of the article", @class = "ckeditor" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticleBody, string.Empty)
</div>
```

In my Action in my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ArticleViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the userID who created the article
                User usr = userrepo.FindByUsername(User.Identity.Name);
                model.UsernameID = usr.user_id;

                repository.AddArticle(model.Title, model.Description, model.ArticleBody);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ae)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ae.Message);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

But in my repository I get : `Cannot convert type 'string' to 'byte[]'`

Repository:

```
public void AddArticle(string Title, string Description, string ArticleBody)
    {
        item Item = new item()
        {
            item_title = Title,
            item_description = Description,
            article_body = ArticleBody,
            item_createddate = DateTime.Now,
            item_approved = false,
            user_id = 1,
            district_id = 2,
            link = "",
            type = GetType("Article")
        };

        try
        {
            AddItem(Item);
        }

        catch (ArgumentException ae)
        {
            throw ae;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. " +
                "If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.");
        }

        Save();
        // Immediately persist the User data

    }
```

Can somebody give me a start or help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be Repository method format like

```
Public void AddArticle(string title, string  Description, string ArticleBody)
{
//logic
}
```

I think your repository method have  byte type for any one argument . Check that like my method format .

**Edit:**

Check your `article_body` column  data type in your database? its should me `Nvarchar(Max)` .

Comment: Updated begin post. Yes it is string ArticleBody but when I try to create a new item it says Can't convert to byte

Comment: What's your article_body column  data type in your database ?

Comment: In my mysql database it is "BLOB", but I have a Model in my VB Project where the datatype is Binary because you can't choose "BLOB" ..

Comment: What ? Change your Data Type  byte to nvarchar(Max) like (string)> And update your Edmx or dbml file .

Comment: Now I get another error : A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ArticleBody="<p>sqdsqdsqdsq</p>
").

Comment: Add this line in your webconfiq
 '<system.web>
<httpRuntime   requestValidationMode="2.0" />
 </system.web>'